# Что делать, если Xml-файл с ошибкой?

Tags: c#, xml

При обработке xml-файлов с помощью XmlReader наткнулся на проблему: xml-файл, который я обрабатывал (обход файла производил с помощью XmlReader.Read()), оказался с ошибкой (два тега наложилось друг на друга и вылетает ошибка, что такой-то символ не может стоять вначале имени). Вариантов исправить xml-файл нет, так как он очень большого объёма.
После вылета ошибки обработка заканчивается, а мне бы как-нибудь продолжить её дальше...

Пробовал отловить try-catch и самовольно сделать XmlReader.Read() или XmlReader.Skip(), но обработка всё равно не продолжается. Удивлюсь, если нет решения этой проблемы и придется обрабатывать xml-ки как текстовый файл со своим блэкджеком и...

```
//var xMreader = XmlReader.Create(nameXmlFile); //так было до подсказки
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings {CheckCharacters = false};
var xMreader = XmlReader.Create(nameXmlFile, settings);            
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        while (xMreader.Read())
        {
            if (xMreader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element) continue;
            //обработка
        }
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        //неудачная попытка "перепрыгнуть" через ошибочный участок xml

        //запись ошибки в лог                   
    }
}
```

Пример ошибочного xml(ошибка в node c id=2, где второй раз {31Z"**2**013..}):

```
<test>
<node id="1" version="1" timestamp="2013-03-25T13:56:31Z" changeset="15491865" uid="322785" user="BCNorwich"/>
<node id="2" version="1" timestamp="2013-03-25T13:56:31Z"2013-03-25T13:56:31Z"changeset="15491865" uid="322785" user="BCNorwich"/>
<node id="3" version="1" timestamp="2013-03-25T13:56:31Z" changeset="15491865" uid="322785" user="BCNorwich"/>
<node id="4" version="1" timestamp="2013-03-25T13:56:31Z" changeset="15491865" uid="322785" user="BCNorwich"/>
<node id="5" version="1" timestamp="2013-03-25T13:56:31Z" changeset="15491865" uid="322785" user="BCNorwich"/>
<node id="6" version="1" timestamp="2013-03-25T13:56:31Z" changeset="15491865" uid="322785" user="BCNorwich"/>
</test>
```

Comment: А если использовать `XmlReaderSettings.CheckCharacters = false`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP к сожалению, ошибка также вылетает и обработка далее не происходит(

Comment: дополните пжалста, свой вопрос кодом, в т.ч. с блоком обработки `try-catch`.

Comment: @Alias добавил)

Comment: а можно увидеть, как выглядит ошибочное место в xml?

Comment: и у документа, который вы читаете, есть схема?

Comment: В общем случае это невозможно. Файл, который вы читаете, **более не является XML-файлом**. В частном случае конкретного исходного файла и конкретного типа ошибки иногда может быть придумана процедура восстановления.

Comment: @VladD неужели нет способа, при ошибочном node, перепрыгнуть на следующий...если xml-файл весит, к примеру, 100 Гб, дважды не хотелось бы его проходить (первый раз исправлять ошибки, второй - парсить)

Comment: @Sublihim схема, как я понял, это грубо говоря шаблон моего xml-документа. конкретно файла со схемой у меня нет, но если реализация через схему возможна, то можно сделать. Почитал я немного про валидацию по схеме, но одно дело, когда программа кричит, что "xml не валидный там-то там-то", а мне нужно пропустить невалидный node.

Comment: Имхо, если узел не валидный, то как продолжать работу дальше? Там же весь последующий XML сыпется, если что-то забыли закрыть.

Comment: @iluxa1810 может, такое быть, конечно, но в моих тестовых xml встречалось только подобное, что я выложил в вопросе: ошибка внутри самого node. А закрытие и открытие везде правильное.

Comment: @PavelNewSky: Общего способа? Нет, конечно. Ну вот пример, получаете вы такой ошибочный XML: `<root></qqqq>`. Или такой: `</root></abcd></efgh>`. Наши действия?

Comment: спс за интересный вопрос, жаль что стандартными средствами никак     :(

Comment: @VladD действительно, общего способа для всех ошибок не найти. но если все теги открываются/закрываются правильно(как в моем случае), то как перескочить через ошибочный узел то должен быть ответ.

Comment: @PavelNewSky Имхо, майкрософт не стали бы делать решения, которые работаю только для конкретных исключений => остается ручками перебирать.

Comment: @PavelNewSky дело в том, что в вашем случае - это синтаксическая ошибка в XML. После ее обнаружения, действительно ридер становится невалидным и читать далее XML больше невозможно. Можно наверное попробовать исхитрится и использовать ReadSubtree и потом перебирать сиблингов, и если возникнет исключение, оно возникнет уже в конкретном ридере. Но для этого надо обладать информацией о структуре документа (но это я лишь теоретизирую). В целом решения, кроме как перебирать самописным ридером, или поймав исключение, править ситуацию в самом файле ручками, и потом возобновить разбор - нет.

Comment: @Sublihim ReadSubtree, к сожалению, не подойдет(будет отбрасывать все, что далее в Subtree находится). и я пришёл к тому же выводу, что и до заданного вопроса, стоит писать свой парсер. ну хорошо, зато я теперь уверен в том, что нет какого-то очевидного решения, которое я мог бы упустить.